# View Prometheus custom metrics received using prometheusremotewrite

Tags: prometheus, metrics

I've an application which uses OpenTelemetry to produce telemetry data and send them to the OpenTelemetry Collector. Then, the OpenTelemetry Collector uses the "prometheusremotewrite" exporter to write telemetry data to an instance of Prometheus using the api /api/v1/write. Both the Collector and Prometheus are deployed as Docker containers.

I'm able to view custom metrics on the Prometheus UI (in my case, http://localhost:9090) but I don't know how to retrieve all custom metrics to visualize them inside another monitoring tool using a specific endpoint (for example, http://localhost:9090/metrics where I don't find my generated custom metrics).

I've tryed to use /federate endpoint as suggested inside another topic but it didn't solve the problem.

Does anyone has already faced this problem? Thank you

Comment: Prometheus has [API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/) that is usually used to retrieve data for visualization.

Comment: @markalex I’ve found a solution for my use case. My third parties monitoring tool scrapes metrics as prometheus so it need a specific endoint where all metrics are available (something like /metrics, where I was able to found all metrics except for custom metrics generated by OpenTelemetry). I’m now able to get my custom metrics directly from the otel collector, which exposes these metrics under port 8889 which is used for prometheus scraping (I can potentially delete Prometheus now from my architecture)